# Download Folder Structure from GitHub

Tags: github

A bit of a newbie question. I see a repo on GitHub with a specific folder structure but when I download it I get a different image. What is the issue?

FYI the repo is : https://github.com/spbooks/angularjs1

Thanks!

Comment: What is different about your structure exactly?

Comment: Did you use `git clone https://github.com/spbooks/angularjs1.git` to download or downloaded a zip?

Comment: The best about this question is that @Mike included a link to the repo. It's so rare for github-related questions.

Comment: I just needed to clone... A little stupid of me... The Export that I was downloading however did NOT have the 'Chapter' forlders, but was a flat structure of different files. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just cloned a repo with

```
git clone https://github.com/spbooks/angularjs1.git
```

It's alsolutely the same as in the repo, both folder structure and files.

UPD: downloaded a zip, it's also just the same.

So, try cloning a repo.